# VBA Cell interior color, fade from black to white

Tags: vba, transition, fade

Im using Excel 2003 and would like to know the best way to change a cell's interior colour from black, and then gradually fade to white.

The idea being I will use the worksheet change event to slowly reveal some black text that is put into the cell in question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub tester()
    FadeToWhite Selection.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub

Sub FadeToWhite(c As Range)
    Const SLOWNESS As Long = 300000
    Dim i As Long, v
    For i = 1 To 255 * SLOWNESS
        If i Mod SLOWNESS = 0 Then
            v = i / SLOWNESS
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(v, v, v)
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to write a `Sub Pause` routine also.  That way you can more easily control the speed of the transition.

Comment: wow, that's pretty awesome!