# Why is title populating after the animation?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA function that modifies the contents of two fields then [flashes the background color for one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24124414/736893).  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cellTitle As Range
    Set cellTitle = Range("J2")
    Dim cellTip As Range
    Set cellTip = Range("J3")
    Title = Application.VLookup(Target.Address, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(Title) Then
        Tip = Application.VLookup(Target.Address, Sheets("Settings").Range("TipsDashboard"), 3, False)
        cellTitle.Value = Title
        cellTip.Value = Tip
        FadeToWhite (Sheets("Dashboard").Range("$J$3:$K$9"))
    End If
End Sub

Sub FadeToWhite(c As Range)
    Const SLOWNESS As Long = 50000
    Dim i As Long, v
    For i = 1 To 255 * SLOWNESS
        If i Mod SLOWNESS = 0 Then
            v = i / SLOWNESS
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(v, 255, v)
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

For some reason, it populates the value of `cellTip`, does the color fade, *then* populates the value of `cellTitle`.  My delay will ultimately be much slower, but the larger value for `SLOWNESS` really makes the timing obvious.

I realize this is a tiny, innocuous detail, but I really want to understand why it's happening.

Comment: *I am not able to replicate your problem.* Your code seems to work in the small demo I put together. I had to remove `.Address` from `Target` in the VLOOKUP calls, but that is not the cause for your problem. If you click on two or three cells in succession, it can cause the Fade routine to behave a little strange. However, Title appears in J2 as / before Tip appears in J3.

Comment: Here is a stripped down, new document, that still exhibit the symptoms for me.  Can you check it out?  http://ge.tt/2zgxLoZ2

Comment: It seems inconsistent.  I wonder if it's just a processing load thing?  My PC is beefy though.  Either way, I think I'll have to remove this before distribution.

Comment: Grasping here, but [Excel's calculation sequence](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm) may be contributing. Just for grins, try putting this equation in some innocuous cell `=J2` and see if the behavior changes.